# In Rust, is there a way to subclass `gstreamer::Bin` such that I still have its original methods?

Tags: rust, gstreamer, glib

I am trying to subclass `gstreamer::Bin` to override its `Bin::handle_message` method, with the intention of intercepting end-of-stream messages, dropping them and signalling that they were dropped (using the default `Bin::handle_message` behaviour if they're not end-of-stream messages).

The thing is, I still need its original methods (like `Bin::add`, `Bin::add_pad` and such) because the only behaviour that I need stacked on top of the original `gstreamer::Bin` is the message interception like previously mentioned.

I mention that I still need its original methods because when I tried to follow [this](https://docs.rs/glib/0.10.1/glib/subclass/index.html) example, the resulting `CustomBin` that I wrote did not satisfy `IsA<Bin>`, and, thus, was not eligible for the blanket implementation of `gstreamer::GstBinExt`, which in turn made it not have the original `gstreamer::Bin` methods.

I also came across [this](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-rs/-/blob/master/tutorial/src/progressbin.rs) example, but ultimately I do not want to reimplement the message interception behaviour for every set of elements that I want to dynamically add and remove from my pipeline. I also don't need to register it as an element proper, I just need to use it within my own crate, and the pipelines defined in it.

For reference, I am going to attach below my attempt of achieving this.

What am I missing?

---

```rust
pub struct CustomBin {
    eos_guard: Mutex<Option<Sender<()>>>,
}

impl Default for CustomBin {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self {
            eos_guard: Mutex::new(None),
        }
    }
}

impl ObjectImpl for CustomBin {
    glib_object_impl!();
}

impl ElementImpl for CustomBin {}

impl BinImpl for CustomBin {
    fn handle_message(&self, bin: &Bin, message: Message) {
        if let MessageView::Eos(_) = message.view() {
            if let Some(sender) = self.eos_guard.lock().unwrap().take() {
                sender.send(()).unwrap_or(());
            } else {
                self.parent_handle_message(bin, message);
            }
        } else {
            self.parent_handle_message(bin, message);
        }
    }
}

impl ObjectSubclass for CustomBin {
    const NAME: &'static str = "GstCustomBin";
    type ParentType = Bin;
    type Instance = ElementInstanceStruct<Self>;
    type Class = ClassStruct<Self>;

    glib_object_subclass!();

    fn new() -> Self {
        Self::default()
    }
}

impl CustomBin {
    pub fn install_eos_guard(&self) -> Receiver<()> {
        let mut eos_guard = self.eos_guard.lock().unwrap();
        let (sender, receiver) = channel();

        if eos_guard.is_some() {
            panic!("End-of-stream guard was already installed");
        } else {
            eos_guard.replace(sender);
        }

        receiver
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need at least the `class_init` + `klass.set_metadata` implementations as well in the ObjectSubClass implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `CustomBin` struct is the internal implementation of the type and not a `glib::Object` (or `gst::Bin`) by itself. If you compare it with e.g. Java then this is all the private fields and protected virtual methods.

This is sufficient to create a new instance and also to use it as any of its parent classes

```rust
let obj: glib::Object = glib::Object::new(CustomBin::get_type(), &[("name", "bla")]).unwrap();
let bin: gst::Bin = obj.downcast::<gst::Bin>().unwrap();
```

Note that `obj` and `bin` above are not your `CustomBin` struct.

To create a public Rust API around your `CustomBin` you would use the [`glib_wrapper!`](https://gtk-rs.org/docs/glib/macro.glib_wrapper.html) macro. You can find an example of that [here](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer-rs/-/blob/a4239c34621ad84b6daedde1cdadb8a8e16a03b4/examples/src/bin/subclass.rs#L255-290). Don't look only at those highlighted lines but also all the code above it.

Comment: After following the examples you posted, I am getting two similar errors: 1) `(process:29533): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 12:06:52.310: ../../../gobject/gsignal.c:1763: parameter 1 of type '<invalid>' for signal "GstBus::sync-message" is not a value type` and 2) is the same as the first but for `"GstBus::message"` instead. What am I missing?

Comment: I found out this morning I had forgotten to call `gstreamer::init()` when I was testing the structure. Other than that, I implemented the examples you pointed me to and it's working just fine. Once again, thank you very much.